# ffmpeg picture slideshow with audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a batch of videos for uploading to youtube. My emphasis is on the audio (mostly MP3, with some WMA). I have several image files that need to be picked up at random to go with the audio (ie) display an image for 5 seconds before showing the next. I want the video to stop when the audio stream ends. How should I use ffmpeg to achieve this ?

Ref:

http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: The example didnt include random selection of images, copying the audio stream without converting, stopping when the audio stream ends when there is no loop in video. Thank you for the response.

Comment: The examples show how to do all of that except the random image selection. You may be able to do that with the [`select`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filter using the [`random(x)`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) function.

Comment: I tried   ffmpeg -i "C:\audio.mp3" -f image2 -r 1/10 -i "C:\img%d.jpg" -c:a copy -c:v copy -r 30 -y -shortest -vf select='random(2000)' "C:\out.mkv". It doesnt seem to work. Also, the video doesnt stop when the audio stops. Thank you.

Comment: You may get a working `select` example by asking the [ffmpeg-user mailing list](http://ffmpeg.org/contact.html).